# How to add prefix to primary key?

Tags: mysql, primary-key, primary-key-design

I have `student table` with `admission id`, i want to add prefix to that `admission id` when i registered

Std Table:

```
S_AdminID  S_Name S_Gender
1          eeee   M
2          gggg   F
```

14AD is added to asdmission id 
I want like this

```
S_AdminID      S_Name   S_Gender
14AD1          eeee     M
14AD2          gggg     F
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is this auto-generated ID at the moment?

Comment: Do you want to visualize only this "prefix", or do you want to store it in the table?

Answer (score 2):

```
UPDATE table set S_AdminID=CONCAT("14AD",S_AdminID)
```

But that may effect if your table attribute is of `int` or `autoincrement`

## [Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b3686/1)

If you want it automatically then you can use **[Triggers](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/trigger-syntax.html)**

Example:

```
CREATE TRIGGER test BEFORE INSERT ON table_name
FOR EACH ROW SET @S_AdminID = CONCAT('14AD' ,@S_AdminID);
```

If you want to use prefix with **Primary key** , **Auto increment**. Then you have to make some change in table schema like:

```
CREATE TABLE myItems (
    id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    prefix CHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id, prefix),
```

Comment: i dont want to update, during registration itself prefix should be added .

Comment: well then you should show the INSERT query that works on registration

Comment: Insert into Std_table(S_Name,S_Gender) values('gggg','F')

Comment: @GuruKumar you can do this is server side scripting language **PHP** or using **Trigger**.

Comment: when i execute this query , s_admissionid is a primary key and auto increment 

Output should be
14AD005 gggg F
14AD006 tyht M



like this i want

Comment: CREATE TABLE table1_seq
(
  id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
);
CREATE TABLE table1
(
  id VARCHAR(7) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY DEFAULT '0', name VARCHAR(30)
);

Now the trigger

DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER tg_table1_insert
BEFORE INSERT ON table1
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO table1_seq VALUES (NULL);
  SET NEW.id = CONCAT('LHPL', LPAD(LAST_INSERT_ID(), 3, '0'));
END$$
DELIMITER ;

Then you just insert rows to table1

INSERT INTO Table1 (name) 
VALUES ('Jhon'), ('Mark');

And you'll have

|      ID | NAME |
------------------
| LHPL001 | Jhon |
| LHPL002 | Mark |